# Storing arrays in javascript for javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, serialization

I've seen lots of articles on how to serialise arrays from javascript to send to PHP files which the PHP file will then deserialise back into an array, etc...

I have a large-ish nested associative array in my javascript which I need to save to a string and at a later date retrieve and convert back into a string *in javascript*. No other program will ever touch this. It may be handy if the serialised data is human-readable but it is absolutely not a requirement.

There is an intermediate PHP file but it's only 4 lines long: all it does is save the string to a file and send it back when requested. I'm not interested in parsing the array in PHP.

What is the fastest and simplest way to convert a multi-nested associative array in javascript to a string and back again?

Comment: Have you looked into JSON? (Also, I assume by "associative array" you mean "object"?)

Comment: Well, I have constructed my array like: `var data = new Array(); data["John"] = "John Smith";` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSON](http://json.org/) is a subset of the JavaScript language that is widely used as a serialization format, both for JavaScript and increasingly for other languages as well. It's human-readable, except that most implementations remove optional whitespace, which makes it a bit more difficult.

Modern browsers have JSON support out-of-the-box, for older ones you will need to include a library like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

To serialize, you use the `JSON.stringify` method.

```
var myObject = {a: 2, b: 3, c: [1, 2, 3]};
var serialized = JSON.stringify(myObject);
// serialized == "{"a":2,"b":3,"c":[1,2,3]}"
```

To unserialize, you use the `JSON.parse` method.

```
var recovered = JSON.parse(serialized);
```

---

> Well, I have constructed my array like: `var data = new Array(); data["John"] = "John Smith";`

Ah, this is a problem. A JavaScript `Array` isn't meant to be used as an associative array, it's meant as a normal zero-indexed non-associative array. You can assign properties (key/value pairs) to any JavaScript object, which is why your code is working, but the fact thay your object is an `Array` is probably going to cause problems. If you just create a `new Object()` instead things should work better.

Comment: JSON.stringify() returns `[null,null,`...`,null,[]]` however I'm absolutely positive that my array is populated.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in the process of re-writing my code (yuck) to use objects rather than associative arrays. I did a quick test and the JSON stringify works perfectly with objects.

Comment: It should work fine with arrays too as long as you only use "normal" numeric indexes (which includes array literals like `["something","something else","etc]`).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to serialize your array into JSON:

```
serialized = JSON.stringify(myobject)
```

To get it back

```
myobject = JSON.parse(serialized)
```

http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var someArray = [];
someArray.push({someObjectProperty: 'someValue' });
someArray.push({someObjectProperty: 'someValue2' });

console.log(someArray);

var stringVersion = JSON.stringify(someArray);//You can save the string version anywhere...

console.log(stringVersion);

var someNewArray = JSON.parse(stringVersion);

console.log(someNewArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has explained this well on the Javascript side, but this is how it happens on the PHP side:

```
<?php
  $arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c');  // an array in PHP

  echo json_encode($arr); // output the array as JSON: [1,2,3,'a','b','c']
?>

<?php
  $json = "[1,2,3,'a','b','c']"; // a JSON string to be parsed by PHP

  $arr = json_decode($json); // this is our original array in PHP again
?>
```